# Generalization of Binomial Coefficients to any non negative real number.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers, products

How could we put a product of $n$ values, $x_{1},\, x_{2},\,\,\,\,\,....x_{n}$ into binomial coefficients. I mean $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=$ Some expression involving binomial coefficients. Note that all $x_{i}$ are non-negative real numbers and having the relation $x_{1}\geq x_{2}\geq x_{3}....\geq x_{n}$. Relation to Gamma function or factorial function will also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by "into binomial coefficients"

Comment: How about
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\binom{x_i}{1}}?$$

Comment: Yes,  it works but now actually i want to relate this to factorial function or Gamma function in which i am facing trouble, any idea, Dear @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris. Thank you very much

Comment: If $n=1$ then the product is just $x_1$ which is equal to itself. What more do you want?

Comment: i want to replace this product by some expression involving Factorial function or Gamma function. As i have seen that this has a relation to factorial or gamma function but i dont know the actual way how to do this.@Somos